# Using Reflection to query an entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to read an assembly containing the base classes of the entity framework and the use the type info to Activate or create a class of the same.

I wanted to use the type info to dynamically query and list of all columns and data in the database. Basically a single to place to list all table's contents.

Some code as below:

```
 private  Type GetInstanceType(string tableName)
 {
   return Assembly.Load("EntityFrameWorkDLLName").GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tableName);          
 }

 public void GetEntityList(string name)
 {
  // the list method where I pass the table name to query table using the db context
   var instanceType =GetInstanceType(name);

        if (instanceType != null)
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceType)
            db.obj.Select();// here I am stuck without knowing how to proceed
  or db.Set<obj.GetType()> // this also fails with error '<' cannot be applied to operands of 'method group' and 'Type'
        }
 }
```

May be what I am trying to do is pretty ridiculous, but can someone point out why? if I could use concrete instance .gettype to stand for the type parameter in generics wont it be good, for then any object can dynamically be hooked in place?

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: for eg: if I pass in table name "User" present in my EF dll, then the type would resolve to the User table in the database and list all users data.

Comment: If the end result is the list of users, why not use EF directly like **dbContext.Users**? I'm not seeing the need of reflection here.

Comment: Today i know Users, tomorrow it can be anything. I don't want to hardcode to Users alone. I want the code to infer the table class..

Comment: If you do not know a table name on the design time, you cannot use Entity Framework. I'm afraid you will have to use store procedure or generate SQL query on-the-fly.

Comment: Then isn't c# as a language inadequate??

Answer (score 0):

To answer this portion of the question, which I think is the reason for the question...

> I wanted to use the type info to dynamically query and list of all
>   columns and data in the database. Basically a single to place to list
>   all tables.

Have you considered just using INFORMATION_SCHEMA on the database instead?

```
SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need it to work on C#. My tables would get added and updated in the edmx but I dont want to change the C# project referencing the ef dll. Through url i send the table name I need to query and I must be able to infer the type and list the contents.